# List all objects from two models in one view

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models. Campaign and Placement. Every placement object is related to only one campaign object. I want to list all Campaign objects with all placements related.

Campaign #1
 - Placement #1
 - Placement #2
Campaign #2
 - Placement #3
 - Placement #4
...

How can I do it with one view and one template?

Campaign model:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
ACTIVE = 1
INACTIVE = 0
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
    (INACTIVE, 'Inactive'),
)
CPC = 'cpc'
CPM = 'cpm'
CPV = 'cpv'
status = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
client_name = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

def __str__(self):
    name = str(self.client_name) + " - " + self.campaign_name
    return name
```

Placement model:

```
class Placement(models.Model):
ACTIVE = 1
INACTIVE = 0
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
    (INACTIVE, 'Inactive'),
)
CPC = 'cpc'
CPM = 'cpm'
CPV = 'cpv'
UNIT_CHOICES = (
    (CPC, 'CPC'),
    (CPM, 'CPM'),
    (CPV, 'CPV'),
)
status = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
campaign_name = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
publisher_name = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
unit_type = models.CharField(default='cpc', choices=UNIT_CHOICES, max_length=3)
units = models.IntegerField(default=0)
budget = models.IntegerField(default=0)
budget_spent = models.IntegerField(default=0)
units_delivered = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.publisher_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for campaign in campaigns %}
  {{ campaign.campaign_name }}
  {% for placement in campaign.placement_set.all %}
    {{ placement.status }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note, you really shouldn't call your foreign keys "foo_name"; they point to the actual objects, not the name fields, so they should be called `campaign`, `client` and `publisher`.